# I need to format a string as a phone number in a radgrid winform cell

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

Sounds silly simply, right?

I can format the input, but I have a database that is returning the value as a string.  No matter what I do if it is stored in the database as 1234567890 I get 1234567890 back.  Everything in the database is stored as strictly string numeric data, meaning that there are no letters or special characters, but it is a varchar(10) field.

I have created a GridViewMaskBox column and set it to Numeric, then in the formatting event  changed the data to numeric like this:

```
GridViewMaskBoxColumn maskBoxColumn = new GridViewMaskBoxColumn();
        maskBoxColumn.Name = "Phone";
        maskBoxColumn.FieldName = "cellphone_number";
        maskBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Phone";
        maskBoxColumn.MaskType = MaskType.Numeric;
        maskBoxColumn.Mask = "(000) 000-0000";
        maskBoxColumn.TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        maskBoxColumn.ReadOnly = false;
        radGridView1.MasterTemplate.Columns.Add(maskBoxColumn);
```

Then in the CellFormatting event:

```
  if (e.Column.Name=="cellPhone")
            {
                long cellInfo =Convert.ToInt64(e.CellElement.Value);
                 e.CellElement.Value = cellInfo;
            }
```

I even tried just for testing purpose:

```
      if (e.Column.Name=="cellPhone")
            {
                long cellInfo =Convert.ToInt64(e.CellElement.Value);
                long number = 1234567890;
                 e.CellElement.Value = number;
            }
```

and the cell still shows 123456789 instead of (123) 456-7890

I have tried creating a standard text column and using every variation of:
 radGridView1.Columns["cellPhone"].FormatString = "{0:(###) ###-####}";
then again in the formatting event changing from string to a int64.
I have verified in the debugger that it is indeed hitting the event and changing the data type correctly.

I am ready to make small animal sacrifices but fear that will not actually help and may hinder any good karma I have built up.
Please help.  I have spent hours on what should have been childs play.

Joe

Update: I can do the below which seems to work, but actually replaces the text in the grid with the "()" in the numbers which screws the database update on edit:

```
 if (e.CellElement.Value.ToString().Length==10)
                {
                    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger();
                       bool worked = BigInteger.TryParse(e.CellElement.Value.ToString(),out bi);
                       string numberAsText = bi.ToString("###-###-####");
                       e.CellElement.Value = numberAsText.ToString();}
```

I think I am chasing my tail...

UPDATE:
I have now added a new (non databound) column called cellMasked and I have the following single codeline in the CellFormating event for the databound cellphone column:

```
 e.Row.Cells["cellMasked"].Value = Convert.ToUInt64(e.CellElement.Value).ToString("###-###-####");
```

Still working on it but it feels like a step in the right direction.

Comment: in DevExpress we have DisplaText property not sure about radgrid

Answer (score 1):

Hold! Don't kill no animals :).

First, I want to start by explaining that the CellFormatting event is used for appearance modifications as the grid uses UI virtualization for its cells. So, setting the Value is not something you should do there, however, setting the CellElement.Text is something you might want. I.e you can change the text to anything you want and this is what you should do in your case.

In regards to the Columns' Mask and MaskType properties, they are responsible for the editor of the cells (when you open it for edit).

Here is a small example I put for you:

```
 protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
 {
     base.OnLoad(e);

     AddGrid();

     DataTable table = new DataTable();
     table.Columns.Add("cellphone_number");
     table.Rows.Add("1234567890");
     table.Rows.Add("3214567890");
     table.Rows.Add("9874567890");

     radGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
     radGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = GridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
     radGridView1.DataSource = table;

     GridViewMaskBoxColumn maskBoxColumn = new GridViewMaskBoxColumn();
     maskBoxColumn.Name = "Phone";
     maskBoxColumn.FieldName = "cellphone_number";
     maskBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Phone";
     maskBoxColumn.MaskType = MaskType.Standard;
     maskBoxColumn.Mask = "(999) 000-0000";
     radGridView1.MasterTemplate.Columns.Add(maskBoxColumn);
     radGridView1.CellFormatting += radGridView1_CellFormatting;
 }

 void radGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.CellFormattingEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.Column.Name == "Phone")
     {
         e.CellElement.Text = Convert.ToUInt64(e.CellElement.Value).ToString("(###)-###-####");
     }
 }
```